# How to calculate Sensor Pixel Pitch?

Tags: focal-length, sensor-size, cmos-image-sensor, pixels

I need to compute the “Sensor Pixel Pitch (in mm/px)”  for some calculation. I have the following data available from the manufacturer:

```
Resolution: 1920x1200
Sensor Type: 2/3” CMOS
Pixel size: 4.8 x 4.8 µm
```

So, far I just found that the sensor pixel pitch the distance between one pixel to next but I do not know how can I compute that value from the above data.

Comment: Did you read the last line there? 4.8 µm = 0.0048 mm...

Comment: @twalberg: That's pixel size but what I found on other articles is that `sensor pixel pitch = distance between two pixels`...Are pixel size and pixel pitch the same thing?

Comment: 8.8*1000/4.8 ≈ 1833 pixels, which is less than the specified 1920 pixels in width. You need to know the dimensions of the sensor down to the micrometer

Comment: @timvrhn Where are you getting 8.8 from?

Comment: @mattdm a 2/3" sensor is approximately 8.8mm in width

Comment: @skm IMHO they're close enough to the same thing. I don't think there's much, if any, significant inter-sensel space, and even if there is, finding the specs for it is going to be difficult.

Comment: For verification - note that calculating the diagonal of the sensor with 1920x1200 pixels of 0.0048mm gives 10.8679mm, which is pretty close to the nominal size of that sensor...

Comment: @timvrhn Well, it's approximately [two-thirds of 16mm diagonal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/why-is-a-1-sensor-actually-13-2-%c3%97-8-8mm). In this case, if the readout is from the full sensor, note that it's an 8:5 aspect ratio rather than the typical 4:3.

Comment: I agree with twalberg — it's just a question of precision, which comes down to needing to know _why_ you need this number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP states in comment "I don't have the exact sensor size" -- well, then, this question can't be answered unless you specify that a "meh, close enough" answer will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't from this information, because "pixel pitch" is: sensor length divided by number of pixels along that dimension. You don't have sensor size — the 2/3" designation is generally *around* 11mm diagonal, but can vary in specifics.

It's possible that "pixel size" in this spec also means "pixel pitch", but it's also possible that that's been measured in a different way. The given number lines up reasonably well (given a 1920×1200 sensor, that'd be a diagonal of about 10.9mm).

Depending on your needs, that might be close enough. Do you have the exact dimensions of the imaging area from which the 1920×1200 readout is produced? If you need more precision, you'll need that.

From your comment:

> Are pixel size and pixel pitch the same thing?

Not necessarily: pixel pitch is measured from center to center, and it's possible that there is a small gap between each pixel so this would be different from pixel size. However, if your purpose in knowing this number is a general sense of the light-collection area of each pixel in comparing camera specs, it's close enough that it doesn't matter.

If your purpose is precise measurement, you probably need to actually do in-the-field measurements based on your *actual total system in practice* rather than making theoretical assumptions. This is especially the case when the tool you are buying is made and marketing as a device for making images but you want to use it instead as a measuring device.

Comment: I don't have the exact sensor size.

Comment: In that case, we're stuck at "you can't".